# Android/Kotlin passing data from a spinner in one fragment to RecyclerView in another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Working on a small app with two Fragments, the second Fragment contains a couple spinners. I want to pass the user selection from the spinner to a recyclerView in the first Fragment. And I am stuck.

Looking at the Android documentation here: [Spinner Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#SelectListener)

The last sentence in that doc says:

> If you implement the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener interface with your Activity or Fragment (such as in the example above), you can pass this as the interface instance.

I'm a dirty newbie....I do not understand what is meant by "pass this as the interface instance"

This is my spinner code from the second Fragment

**CreateNewJobFragment.kt**

```
//String array. Move this to res/strings
    val theTown = arrayOf("Dublin", "Houston", "Paris", "Auckland", "Bismark")

    val townSpinner = binding.spinnerLocation

    //Adapter for spinner
    townSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, theTown)

    //item selected listener for spinner
    townSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            TODO("not implemented yet") 
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, theTown[p2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            nameSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
        }
    }
```

My newb question is what do I do with 'nameSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = this'?

I have an adapter setup that at the moment is just passing dummy data to my recyclerView

**JobAdapter.kt**

class JobAdapter(private val jobList: ArrayList) : RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
//Returning view for each item in the list
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): JobAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.job_list_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

//Binding the data on the list
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(jobList[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return jobList.size
}

//Class holds the job list view
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItems(job: JobData) {
        val textViewCompnayName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_companyName) as TextView
        val textViewLocation  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_job_location) as TextView
        textViewCompnayName.text = job.companyName
        textViewLocation.text = job.location
    }
}
```

}

And a data class for it.

**JobData.kt**

```
data class JobData(val companyName: String,
               val location: String)
```

I'm fairly...ish certian I need to use utilize my JobAdapter to handle this. But I am not able to get it to work. I'm also looking at [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#kotlin), but have not figured out how to get this going.

Anyone wanna point me in the right direction?